# Roundcube Address Book: Can it be bridged with another web application?

Tags: php, synchronization, roundcube

I  have a contact manage app that allows users to add/edit/delete contacts and their information.  I am looking to bridge my application with Roundcube's address book so that I can add/edit/delete contact information from my app within Roundcube's address book.  And to also preserve as much functionality I can from the mail side of things.  For example, when clicking on a contact from within the address book, it will still allow you to compose a message to that person.  Note that I am using Roundcube 0.5.2 and the version cannot be changed.

Currently my app can handle HTTP requests allowing users to retrieve contact information through GET requests or add/edit contacts through PUT/POST requests (the requests have an XML body).  So that is one possible method, but it sounds like it would require a lot of modification into the Roundcube side.

Another possible option would be to "tear out" the Roundcube address book and embed my own application.  Although, I am still new to Roundcube so this may not be possible.

My app has a lot of functionality that relies on the contacts database, so I don't want to connect my app to Roundcube's contact database (although the reverse situation would be acceptable).

I was wondering if anyone here could help guide me in the correct direction on how to handle this situation.